# Delphi Firemonkey XE8 TComboBox is unfolding and closing after a seconds

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe8, tcombobox

I build all `TComboBox` fields programmatically,

all is working fine, with one exception.

In one panel all `TComboBox-fields` are immediately closed after clicking on it.

They are only unfolded for seconds....

What could be a reason for that?
I can't find any differences to the other panels.

Comment: If you show your code, it might be easier for people to assist. :)

Comment: The code will not help, because it is working well at other places, the question is , which event or other activity may cause that immediately closing in general...

Comment: I have found the reason now, from another event the focus was taken to some other control, this caused that closing of TComboBoxes...so all is fine now, thanks